# How to access a public member variable from another class thru an interface?

Tags: c++

Given that I have these classes, how can a member fuction of Bclass access the member variable of Aclass.

```
class Aclass : IAclass {
public:
    int x1;
}


class IAclass { //IA is interface of A

}

class Bclass {
private
 IAclass * a[5];

void Bfunction(){ a[1]->x1;}
}
```

I've tried a[1]->x1 but I am getting the error: IAclass has no member named x1.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you believe `IAclass` is an "interface of A"?

Comment: because he named it IA, its magical

Comment: @gha.st It is on the documentation/comment of the code I am working with.

Comment: @fearfox It doesn't matter what the documentation says. It makes no sense. And your code us syntactically invalid anyway.

Comment: also interfaces should not contain members which are not virtual, call it a abstract class

Comment: @juanchopanza, I've edited the question detail to reflect that one. I didn't look at the class declaration before posting here. Thank you.

Comment: It still makes no sense. And is syntactically invalid.

Answer (score 4):

From BClass, you cannot access anything that is not defined in IAClass. IMHO, that is the entire point of having interfaces, i.e, to separate implementation details from the interface.

Answer (score 1):

your code doesn't reflect your will. you want Aclass to implement IAclass, yet there is no inheritance here.

```
class IAclass { }

class Aclass : public IAclass {
public:
    int x1;
}
```

second of all, your compiler is right. IAclass has no `x1` member.
does an "Animal" have a "tail" property? not necceseraly. a "Worm" does not have tail. a "Cat" has a tail. if the alleged "Animal" is a "Cat" - we first need to treat the animal as a cat, than access it's tail. 
 you need to cast the pointer down (*down cast*) to the right sub-class and then access the variable:

```
Aclass* pA = (Aclass*)&a[1];
pA->x1;
```

of course, `dynamic_cast` is recommended here to actually check the downcast:

```
  Aclass* pA = dynamic_cast<Aclass*>(&a[1]);
  if (pA) {
  pA->x1;
  }
```

`dynamic_cast` will check the down cast on runtime and will return `nullptr` if the downcast fails.

Comment: Don't do this!!!! It defeats the entire purpose of interfaces. Go through a virtual function.

Comment: well, C++ doesn't have Java/C# interfaces. you can make all the functions pure virtual ones. but that doesn't make the class  an "Interface". I went with his example to illustrate down casting.

Comment: Just because they're not enforced by the language doesn't mean you can't write them. If you're going to write an interface, write an interface and don't go casting everything to get at internal implementation details. If you're going to do that, do not write an interface because there is no point.

Comment: you are correct, but you raise a design issue, I answered a syntax issue. he should do what ever you suggested. but it is also important for him to understand why didn't his code worked

Answer (score 0):

The member is on `Aclass`, which is not what `Bclass` sees: the `Bfunction` only sees an `IAclass`.

So you would have to make `x1` a public member of `IAclass`, or give `Bclass` actual `Aclass` objects.

By the way: prefer using an `std::vector` instead of an array, and also prefer using a `shared_ptr<IAclass>` instead of a raw pointer.  Will save you a lot of memory leaks!